# $G=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\}$ let $f\in Hol(G)$ and $|f(z)|\leq e^{-1/|z|}$ for all $z\in G$ prove $f=0$ in G.

Tags: complex-analysis

$G=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\}$ let $f\in Hol(G)$ and $|f(z)|\leq e^{-1/|z|}$ for all $z\in G$ prove $f=0$ in G.
Hint: take R>0 and big enough $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and set $g(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{N-1}f(e^{2i\pi k/N}z+iR)$.

I thought that by taking big enough N that there is a $z_0$ that is  almost under $iR$ and by taking $|z_0|\to 0$ we get that $f(z)=0$ and therefore $g=0$ and by the identity theorem we get $g\equiv 0$ and then $f\equiv 0$ I don't know if this is right and how to make it more formal any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for any radius $R>0$ but for convenience only $R=1$ is considered here. Let $n$ be any positive integer and $\zeta_n = \exp(2 \pi \mathrm i/n)$. For $\lvert z \rvert \leq 1$ let $$g_n(z) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\mathrm i + \zeta_n^k  \mathrm i z)$$ (where we take $f(0)=0$). Then $$\lvert f(\mathrm i) \rvert^n = \lvert g_n(0) \rvert.$$ The key is now to show that $$\lvert g_n(0) \rvert^{1/n} \to 0$$ so that $f(\mathrm i)=0$ (or in the general case $f(\mathrm i R) = 0$). The estimate $$\lvert  1 - e^{\mathrm i \alpha} \rvert = 2 \lvert \sin(\alpha/2) \rvert \leq \lvert \alpha \rvert$$ for any angle $\alpha \in [-\pi, \pi]$ together with the maximum modulus principle suffices for this. The idea is to derive an upper bound for $\lvert g_n \rvert$ on the unit circle by computing a bound for a single factor between all adjacent $n$-th roots of unity and then multiply these.

Comment: very nice elementary solution (+1); the result follows from carleman's theorem as $-1/|t|$ is not integrable around $0$ on the real axis (hence $\log^{-} |f(t)|/(1+t^2)$ is not, where $f(t)$ is the boundary function of $f$ which exists a.e. by Fatou, so $f$ identically zero)

Comment: does't it need to be $f(i+\zeta_n^k z)$